# How to verify if tr/table/td exists

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm using mechanize browser to retrieve some information.
In the search form, if there are no results, my code doesn't work

Here my code

```
list_src =["keyword1","gdfgz", "keyword2"]
i = 0
while (i < 2):
        br2 = mechanize.Browser()
        br2.set_cookiejar(cj)
        br2.open("https://url")
        br2.select_form(nr=0) # this is the search form
        br2.form['sq'] = liste_src[i]
        res2 = br2.submit()
        html2 = res2.read() 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'lxml')
        table1 = soup.findAll("table",{ "width" : "100%" })[13] 
        tr1 = table1.findAll('tr')[3] 
        table2 = tr1.findAll("table",{ "width" : "100%" })[0]
        tr2 = table2.findAll('tr')[1]
```

My error message :

> tr2 = table2.findAll('tr')[1] IndexError: list index out of range

When there are no results, there is not this tr. 
So I've tried to add
if not tr, print 'no results' but it doesn't work.
How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: `try: ... catch IndexError: ...`

Comment: @zvadym Do you mean `try....except`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice right, thanks :)

Comment: You could look at toying with css selectors to get things, something like: `tr1 = soup.select_one('table:nth-of-type(14) tr:nth_of_type(4)')` Then check if that returns anything and act appropriately or even something like: `print(getattr(tr1, 'text', 'No results!'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of tr2 (or any other list) and then iterate over all the elements based on the lists length... Or access any specific index in the list if index < length.

```
idx = 1
tab2trs = table2.findAll('tr')
tr2 = None
if idx < len(tab2trs):
    tr2 = tab2trs[idx]
```

Or you can add a try except...

```
try:
    tr2=table2.findAll('tr')[1]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: Using `if` statements for logic control is preferred over catching an exception.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice why's that? In this case it's expected to be there - if it's not - it's an exception that can be handled elsewhere if needs be... no need to lumber the code with length checking...